# How to use SQL to get records that are distributed evenly from each category?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
category_id    uid    popularity   ts
=======================================
    03
    05
    07
    07
    07
    10
    10
```

For each row, `uid` is unique and each row belongs to certain category, presented by `category_id`. Let's say we have 10 categories in total and there are thousands of records.

I try to make a SQL query that will get 50 records within a certain timeframe sorted by popularity. This can be easily done. However, what if I hope these 50 records are distributed evenly from each category? For example, if there are 10 categories, each has 5 records, there are 50 records in total. Is there a way to do this via one SQL query? Or I have to do this in 10 separate SQL queries?

Comment: Please fill in the rest of your sample table.  What if 50 evenly distributed records cannot be found within a specified timeframe?  What happens then?

Comment: if there are no 50 records can be found, just return as many as possible or just make it a failure case.

Comment: Do you want the records from every category I mean each category should consist of 50 records. Or in any way total 50 records? Try to share sample data.

Comment: 5 records from each category, so there are 50 records in total

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable where categoryid = 1 order by popularity desc limit 10
union all
select * from mytable where categoryid = 2 order by popularity desc limit 10
union all
select * from mytable where categoryid = 3 order by popularity desc limit 10
```

Repeat for however many categories you have

Some MySQL wizard can probably tell you how to do it with [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) too.

See: [unions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)